# SQL aggregate error

Tags: sql, count

I have some problem this is the correct code but after I add the count aggregate

```
select 
    c.branch_id, d.DVD_genre, count(c.DVD_catalogno) as Total_DVD
from 
    CatalogNo_No c 
inner join
    DVD d on c.DVD_catalogno = d.DVD_catalogno
where 
    d.DVD_catalogno = d.DVD_genre
order by 
    c.branch_id;
```

I cant execute anymore it pop out an error about column 'CatalogNo_No.branch_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `COUNT()`, you usually want `GROUP BY`.  Almost never do you want `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Try a version like this:

```
select c.branch_id, d.DVD_genre, count(c.DVD_catalogno) as Total_DVD
from CatalogNo_No c inner join
     DVD d
     on c.DVD_catalogno = d.DVD_catalogno
where d.DVD_catalogno = d.DVD_genre
group by c.branch_id, d.DVD_genre
order by c.branch_id;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.
- There is no need to repeat the `ON` conditions in the `WHERE` clause.
- The non-aggregated columns (expressions) go in the `GROUP BY`.